# How to return different result under 1 decorator in the same time in flask python

Tags: python, flask, lstm, python-decorators

I m currently deploying my LSTM model in flask python, I would like to ask how do I return my new CSV file together with my plot graph under one `@app.route` into a page, hence I need some advice and tips regarding this issues.

I got this error when execute the code >> `TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.`

**app.py**

```
@app.route('/transform', methods=["POST"])
def transform_view():
 if request.method == 'POST':
    f = request.files['data_file']
    if not f:
        return "No file"    

    
    stream = io.StringIO(f.stream.read().decode("UTF8"), newline=None)
    csv_input = csv.reader(stream)
    stream.seek(0)
    result = stream.read()
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(result), usecols=[1])
    
    #extract month value
    df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(result))
    matrix2 = df2[df2.columns[0]].to_numpy()
    list1 = matrix2.tolist()
     
    # load the model from disk
    model = load_model('model.h5')
    dataset = df.values
    dataset = dataset.astype('float32')
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
    dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)
    look_back = 1
    dataset_look = create_dataset(dataset, look_back)
    dataset_look = np.reshape(dataset_look, (dataset_look.shape[0], 1, dataset_look.shape[1]))
    predict = model.predict(dataset_look)
    transform = scaler.inverse_transform(predict)

    X_FUTURE = 12
    transform = np.array([])
    last = dataset[-1]
    for i in range(X_FUTURE):
        curr_prediction = model.predict(np.array([last]).reshape(1, look_back, 1))
        last = np.concatenate([last[1:], curr_prediction.reshape(-1)])
        transform = np.concatenate([transform, curr_prediction[0]])
  
    transform = scaler.inverse_transform([transform])[0]

    dicts = []
    curr_date = pd.to_datetime(list1[-1])
    for i in range(X_FUTURE):
        curr_date = curr_date +  relativedelta(months=+1)
        dicts.append({'Predictions': transform[i], "Month": curr_date})


    new_data = pd.DataFrame(dicts).set_index("Month")
    ##df_predict = pd.DataFrame(transform, columns=["predicted value"])

def index(chartID = 'chart_ID', chart_type = 'line', chart_height = 550):
    chart = {"renderTo": chartID, "type": chart_type, "height": chart_height}
    series = [{"name": 'Month', "data": [1,2,3]}]
    title = {"text": 'Time Series Sales Predicting'}
    xAxis = {"categories": ['xAxis Data1', 'xAxis Data2', 'xAxis Data3']}
    yAxis = {"title": {"text": 'Sales'}}
     

    response = make_response(new_data.to_csv(index = True, encoding='utf8'))
    response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=result.csv"
    return response
    return render_template('graph.html', chartID=chartID, chart=chart, series=series, title=title, xAxis=xAxis, yAxis=yAxis)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your error message, your `transform_view()` function does not return anything. Consider adding a `return` statement at the bottom of it, just like you have done for `index()`

```py
@app.route('/transform', methods=["POST"])
def transform_view():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # ...
    return # <your_response>
```

Maintain your `index()` function

```py
def index(chartID = 'chart_ID', chart_type = 'line', chart_height = 550):
    # ...
    return render_template(# ...)
```

Comment: Meaning I have to remove `index()` or transform it into another way? can you give me some suggestions regarding this?

Comment: Hmm, actually I don't really get you, can you explain more details, how do I maintain the `def index`? if I maintain it, I think I will still get error right ?

Comment: The `transform_view()` function does not return anything, as seen from your code, hence the error you are getting. To ensure that it returns something rather than `None`, I suggest you add the `return` statement at the end of that function. If you look at `index()` it has a return statement, but `transform_view()` doesn't. This is the source of your error. Adding a `return` statement should solve it.

Comment: Oh I got what you said and I try follow it , unfortunately, I got return result from `transform_view()` but I dint get return result from `index()`

Comment: You have two return statements used with `index()`. If you use `return response`, then the response/result of the `index` function would be given back (aka returned). This response you can use it elsewhere in your application. However, `return render_template()` simply returns your `graph.html` file with objects defined. Maybe use an `if` statement with the `index()` function. `if <condition>: return response else: abort(...)`....then the `return render_template()` to be used outside of the `if` statement

Comment: But I want to return `response` and `render_template` in the same time or into a page, meaning I want to return these 2 results